# Bootstrap css issue when using with box-sizing, bootstrap input box and icon not aligned correctly

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

In my existing css I have box-sizing styles.

```
*,
*:before,
*:after {
      -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
      -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
      box-sizing: border-box; }
```

Including bootstrap into the project I come to know display of input box and icons using bootstrap is not correct. Investigating through fiddler I come to know it is because of above styles. Please see display of bootstrap styles:

In IE: 
[image]

In FF:
[image]

Below is my html code which use bootstrap styles:

```
 <div class="input-prepend" style="border:dashed 1px;">
        <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
        <input id="handle" type="text" placeholder="Twitter Handle">        
    </div>

Start date
    <div class="input-append date" id="dpFrom"  data-date="@Model.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy")"  data-date-format="dd/mm/yyyy">
        <input class="span2" size="16" value="@Model.StartDate.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy") " readonly="readonly" type="text">
        <span class="add-on" style="border: dashed 1px red;"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span>
    </div>
```

**My Findings**

I tried removing  box-size styles and bootstrap things were fixed but there was another issue. I started getting horizontal scroll bar in my web pages.

I have a little understanding of css but unfortunately I am not able to fix it as I just started Bootstrap 2 days ago. Can you please help me shooting this trouble.

Thanks a lot for your time, guidance and helping me out.

Comment: That's a very bad idea.  You should fix your paddings to remove the extra horizontal space, then get rid of that rule.  The dev tools will help you.

Comment: @SLaks it is existing code, I m not sure why it is and where else it will effect.

Comment: Yes, but that will _completely_ break Bootstrap, as well as any other 3rd-party CSS you use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was boxing sizing issue, for some fields I had to set it to content-box.

Answer (score 0):

By seeing your picture: It's not box-sizing problem but input field space is appearing as different browsers have different style by default. So you should try using `margin: 0; padding: 0;` for input fields

Also defining the height may help you. And apply display inline or inline-block or table-cell for those elements and align it vertically to top or middle.

Comment: Wrong.  He's using Bootstrap to normalize everything, but Bootstrap is getting messed up because the box-sizing is wrong.